# How to return DbRawSqlQuery in Moq setup method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a procedure service which contain only methods like this one:

```
DbRawSqlQuery<UserVesselPermissionsResult> GetUserVesselPermissions(Guid userId, DateTime date);
```

So, all the methods are returning `DbRawSqlQuery`, then in some upper layer of the application I turn them into `IEnumerable`. But for the testing purpose in some places I have to setup this method. The problem is that the class `DbRawSqlQuery` does have a internal constructor(*I know Moq does not accept internal constructors*) but I dont know if there is some way to make this code work:

```
_procedureService.Setup(x => x.GetUserVesselPermissions(It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>()))
            .Returns(new DbRawSqlQuery<UserVesselPermissionsResult>(null));
```

Currently it does not work due to `DbRawSqlQuery` which can not be instantiated easily.

EDIT 1:

Here are some more details:

```
public class IMembershipService
{
    private readonly IProcedureService _procedureService;
    public MembershipService(IProcedureService procedureService)
    {
        _procedureService = procedureService;
    }

    public List<UserVesselPermissionsResult> UserPermissions => _procedureService.GetUserVesselPermissions(UserId, DateTime.Now).ToList();


    public bool UserHasPermissionOrAdmin(YcoEnum.UIPermission permission)
    {
        if (IsUserAdministrator)
            return true;
        var userVesselPermissions = UserVesselPermissions; //Here I have to make the setup
        if (userVesselPermissions == null)
            return false;
        var userSelectedVesselId = UserSelectedVesselId;
        return //something
    } 
}
```

The test method would look like this:

```
[TestCase(true)]
[TestCase(false)]
public void UserHasAllPermissionsOrAdmin_IsAdminOrNot_ReturnsTrue(bool isAdmin)
{ 
    //Arrange
    _membershipService.IsUserAdministrator = isAdmin;
    var claims = new List<Claim>()
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "rajmondi@outlook.com"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    };
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "TestAuthType");
    var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    _authenticationManager.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(claimsPrincipal);

    _procedureService.Setup(x => x.GetUserVesselPermissions(It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>()))
        .Returns((DbRawSqlQuery<UserVesselPermissionsResult>) null);//Here I dont know how to set it up due to DbRawSqlQuery
    //Action

    var result = _membershipService.UserHasAllPermissions(It.IsAny<YcoEnum.UIPermission>());
    //Assert
    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(true));
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: You have tightly coupled your code to 3rd party API which is making it difficult to mock what you do not own. Long story short Moq is unable to do what you want. Consider reviewing current design choices.

Comment: @Nkosi edited the question so you might give me an idea where I have a design issue in the service itself, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could make it work, I actually did not like the idea of changing the whole `IProcedureService` just because it does return a built-int type from entity framework. Since I get the data from the procedure service and return them to `IEnumerable` I only had to care for `GetEnumerator()` method, so what I thought would be to check first how the code was constructed inside, I found that `DbSqlQuery` was inheriting from `DbRawSqlQuery` and did not have the problem of internal constructor. In this case I created a new class called `TestDbSqlQuery` which would inherit from the `DbSqlQuery`. The class look like this:

```
public class TestDbSqlQuery<T> : DbSqlQuery<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly List<T> _innerList; 

    public TestDbSqlQuery(List<T> innerList)
    {
        _innerList = innerList;
    }

    public override IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _innerList.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I added purposely the `Lis<T>` as a param so I can store my data in that list and then use my overriden `IEnumerator<T>`.

So, now the test method would be like this:

```
_procedureService.Setup(x => x.GetUserVesselPermissions(It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>()))
.Returns(new TestDbSqlQuery<UserVesselPermissionsResult>(new List<UserVesselPermissionsResult>
{
    new UserVesselPermissionsResult
    {
        PermissionId = 1
    }
}));
```

and it is working fine, at the end the `TestDbSqlQuery` can be modified as needed but the idea is the same, just store the objects in some container and then retrieve them in `GetEnumerator` method.